same html popover on different elements positioned in different places
I have a dropdown that I wish to show/hide using html popover API under many different elements. The problem is that popover uses id to detect the target, obviously I can't use one id on multiple elements. Is there a way to address this issue so I don't need to hard code the id, using different ids, for each single element?
This is my dropdown that I want to use on multiple, different, elements:
<div popover id="menu">
    ..dropdown content...
</div>

I have this btn on different elements:
<button id="btn" popovertarget="menu"></button>

so the thing I want is to be able to open/close the dropdown, specific to the element that the btn was clicked on. Something like below:
<!-- element 1 -->
<div>
  <button id="btn" popovertarget="menu"></button>
  <div popover id="menu">
    ..dropdown content - same for all elements...
  </div>
</div>

<!-- element 2 -->
<div>
  <button id="btn" popovertarget="menu"></button>
  <div popover id="menu">
    ..dropdown content - same for all elements...
  </div>
</div>

<!-- element 3 -->
<div>
  <button id="btn" popovertarget="menu"></button>
  <div popover id="menu">
    ..dropdown content - same for all elements...
  </div>
</div>

By doing the above, only one btn works to show/hide the dropdown, which is not what I want.

@MisterJojo I know that! I'm just trying to focus on popover API. The content can be anything.

You can use the showPopover, hidePopover methods to show/hide popover using JS instead of direct html.
That will allow you to target same popover from multiple elements and set it's position using the target element.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/showPopover
Here is a sample, you will need to update logic as per your case.


const sBtn1 = document.getElementById("submit1");
const sBtn2 = document.getElementById("submit2");
const outSpan = document.getElementById("menu");

function pop() {
let targetid = event.target.id;
let positiony = event.target.offsetTop;
let positionx = event.target.offsetLeft;

outSpan.style.top = `${positiony + 50}px`;
outSpan.style.left = `${positionx + 50}px`;
console.log(outSpan.style.top, outSpan.style.left);
outSpan.togglePopover();
}
<button id=submit1 onclick="pop()">Submit</button>
<button id=submit2 onclick="pop()">Submit</button>
<div popover="manual" id="menu" >
    ..dropdown content - same for all elements...
  </div>




That can work! can u give me an example please

updated the answer with sample of targeting same popover and changing its position, you will need to put in hide/show logic and values as per your need. Please accept the answer if it helped. Thanks.

So this is the way I'm doing it now, using html popover and css anchor API.


if (window.innerWidth >= 640) {
  document.querySelectorAll('.dots-btn').forEach(btn => {
    btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
      // btn rect
      const btnOffsetTop = btn.offsetTop;
      const btnOffsetLeft = btn.offsetLeft;

      // find the specific popover
      const popoverId = btn.getAttribute('popovertarget');
      const popover = document.getElementById(popoverId);

      if (CSS.supports('position-anchor', 'unset')) {
        // anchor the popover to btn
        popover.style.positionAnchor = `--${popoverId}-btn`;
        btn.style.anchorName = `--${popoverId}-btn`;
      } else {
        // fallback for browsers that don't support html popover
        popover.style.left = `${btnOffsetLeft - 130}px`;
        if (window.innerHeight - btn.getBoundingClientRect().bottom < 350) {
          popover.style.top = `${btnOffsetTop - 300}px`;
        } else {
          popover.style.top = `${btnOffsetTop + 100}px`;
        }
      }
    });
  });



